# Any suggestions on improving the computational speed of this piece of python code?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a following piece of the python code:

```
def ExtendedF(frequency):
    return 1/(1+frequency)

def frequency_critical(gamma, B, alpha):
    return 3 *gamma**2*B*sin(alpha)

def single_spectrum(frequency, gamma, B, alpha):
    freq_c = frequency_critical(gamma, B, alpha)     
    return B*ExtendedF(frequency/freq_c)

def spectra(number_bin, B_field, frequency_bin, energy_bin, alpha_bin):
    #length of number_bin, B_field, alpha_bin is the same
    Spectras = []
    for i in range(len(B_field)):
      Spectra = []
      current_B = B_field[i]
      current_number = number_bin[i] #array of certain length = len
      current_alpha = alpha_bins[i]
      for j in range(len(frequency_bins)):
         single_spectrum = single_spectrum(frequency_bins[j], 
                            energy_bins, current_B, current_alpha)
         Spectra.append(simps(single_spectrum * 
                   append(current_number, array([0])), energy_bins))
      Spectras.append(Spectra)
    return Spectras
```

Since my length of `B_field` is really large, this part of the code is really slow, most probably due to the use of two for loops. Is there any idea on how I could make this code faster. I am assuming numpy array manipulation would be useful, but I am not exactly sure how I would implement this.

Comment: please provide a full, running example. It's hard to help if we cannot even run the code.

Answer (score 0):

To begin with, you don't need to calculate `frequency_critical` in the inner loop, because the variables related to it don't change in the inner loop.
Moreover, you might benefit from pre-allocating memory for `Spectras` and `Spectra` since their size are known.
Finally, you can use list comprehension which might give you a bit of performance boost (But not significant). Something like this:

```
def spectra(number_bin, B_field, frequency_bin, energy_bin, alpha_bin):
    #length of number_bin, B_field, alpha_bin is the same
    Spectras = []
    for i in range(len(B_field)):
        current_number = number_bin[i]
        freq_c = 3*energy_bins**2*B_field[i]*sin(alpha_bins[i])
        Spectra = list(B_field[i] * ExtendedF(freq_j/freq_c) for freq_j in frequency_bins)
        Spectras.append(Spectra)
    return Spectras
```

Of course this line seemed to be incomplete, so I couldn't include it in my answer:

```
     Spectra.append(simps(single_spectrum * 
               append(current_number, array([0])), energy_bins))
```